# I cannot figure out how to fix this problem, can someone help me ? Pirple homework python

Tags: python

Create a global variable called `myUniqueList`. It should be an empty list to start.

Next, create a function that allows you to add things to that list. Anything that's passed to this function should get added to `myUniqueList`, unless its value already exists in `myUniqueList`. If the value doesn't exist already, it should be added and the function should return `True`. If the value does exist, it should not be added, and the function should return `False`;

extra is if we can make the remaining values to a list called my leftovers

```
myUniqueList = []
myLeftovers = []

def addUniqueElement(b):
    if b not in myUniqueList:
        print(myUniqueList.append(b))
        return True
    else:
        myLeftovers.append(newElement)
        return False
    
print(addUniqueElement())
```

Comment: You're missing the argument when you call `addUniqueElement()`

Comment: Thankyou Barmar im very new to this. Could you please give me an example ?

Comment: just finished my answer. In general, since you have  addUniqueElement(b), b represents a argument, so you need to add one.

Answer (score 1):

Something to note is that your attempt was very good. It did everything right except for a few things:

You should print out the list if you want to see the final list
eg.

```
print(myUniqueList)
```

Next, the function requires an argument, in this case, I'll use "cool"
so now we have

```
addUniqueElement("cool")
print(myUniqueList)
```

In the end we get

```
myUniqueList = []
myLeftovers = []

def addUniqueElement(b):
    if b not in myUniqueList:
        print(myUniqueList.append(b))
    else:
        myLeftovers.append(newElement)
addUniqueElement("cool")
print(myUniqueList)
print(myLeftovers)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in printing when you call `myUniqueList.append(b)`. It just updates the list, it doesn't return anything.

You need to pass an argument when you call the function.

`newElement` should be `b`.

```
def addUniqueElement(b):
    if b not in myUniqueList:
        myUniqueList.append(b)
        return True
    else:
        myLeftovers.append(b)
        return False
    
print(addUniqueElement(1)) # True
print(addUniqueElement(2)) # True
print(addUniqueElement(1)) # False
print(addUniqueElement(5)) # True
print(addUniqueElement(10))# True
print(addUniqueElement(5)) # False

print(myUniqueList) # [1, 2, 5, 10]
print(myLeftovers) # [1, 5]
```

Comment: Barmar you are the man ! thankyou so much ive been stuck for days.

Answer (score 0):

here you can continuously add text (ex numbers ) and watch them being added to the one or to the other list

```
    myUniqueList = []
    myLeftovers = []
    
    def addUniqueElement(text):
    
        if text not in myUniqueList:
            myUniqueList.append(text)
            return True
        else:
            myLeftovers.append(text)
            return False
    
    while ( 1 ):
        text = input("text: ")
    
        addUniqueElement(text)
    
        print("myUniqueList: ", myUniqueList)
        print("myLeftovers: ", myLeftovers)
```